# Ubuntu 18 netplan Argument list too long

Tags: network-manager, netplan

I try to add 8k IPs to my network interface with **netplan**, after adding all IPs to yaml netplan config and apply changes, I get the following error:

```
/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0f0.network:1030: Failed to parse file: Argument list too long
```

it looks like at the moment netplan can't parse more than 1030 IPs, can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594004/ubuntu-18-netplan-argument-list-too-long

Comment: show us the exact command you used. If you used `$ sudo bla bla` then try `$ sudo su` followed by `# bla bla` Where the `$` and the `#` are the command line prompts for regular user, `$`, and root, `#`. Why try this? Because the maximum argument length using sudo is pathetic.

Comment: i execute the command "netplan apply" as root, so is not issue with user privileges !

Comment: If it is just a netplan limitation, could you work around it by adding IP addresses from a script using `ip addr add` command instead? A script might be easier to maintain than an argument list of 1030 ip addresses.

Comment: there is still an argument list limit, even for root, it is just way bigger than the sudo limit. There is not a specific number, as it is a function of the per list string size. Try @jtessier72 's suggestion.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, my question is... why are you trying to add 8K IPs in netplan? Show me a subset of your .yaml file.